# How do I add to the BorderLayout.Center?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

I am having trouble adding to the Center of the BorderLayout. Nothing appears on a couple of the screens. This code is still in the works, but it is being designed for a car rental service. We are connecting our code to the JDBC eventually and going to have the database return the corresponding results. The code is ideally supposed to show multiple screens for the user when they use the service. One screen will have them input their information, another to filter through different car options, and then the end result is to display the results returned by the database that is connected. I am adding multiple panels to the center of the BorderLayout but I do not initially set them to be visible. They will become visible when buttons are pressed.

```
//The following is the beginning of our code. It is not complete yet

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rental extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Customer, Car
{
    Container cont = getContentPane();

    Font myFont = new Font("tester ", Font.BOLD, 34);

    BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    GridLayout grid1 = new GridLayout(0,1);

    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(); //Panel where I tried to add to center

    /* myDrive logo */
        JButton custom;

    /*Opening Screen: */ 
    JPanel welcomePnl = new JPanel();
    JLabel titleLbl = new JLabel("");
    //This is a draft summary//
    JLabel info = new JLabel(" Welcome to myDrive!. myDrive is a car rental application designed for you to choose a car based on your preferences.");
    JPanel btnPnl = new JPanel();
    JPanel btnPnl2 = new JPanel(); //contains Car instead of begin

    JCheckBox yesBox = new JCheckBox("Agree to Terms & Conditions");
    JCheckBox noBox = new JCheckBox(" Do Not Agree");

    /* Rental Panel--Screen 2: Fields for user to enter for rental*/
    JPanel rentalPnl = new JPanel();
    JTextField nameField = new JTextField("First Name");
    JTextField lastName = new JTextField("Last Name");
    JButton carBtn = new JButton("Car"); //continues next

    /*Car Panel--Screen 3: Car panel for car options*/
    JPanel carPnl = new JPanel();
    JPanel brandPnl = new JPanel(); //brands
    JPanel colorPnl = new JPanel(); //colors
    JLabel carLbl = new JLabel("Welcome to the Car selection screen:");
    JCheckBox brand1 = new JCheckBox("BMW");
    JCheckBox brand2 = new JCheckBox("Mercedez");
    JCheckBox brand3 = new JCheckBox("Tesla");
    JCheckBox brand4 = new JCheckBox("Ford");
    JCheckBox brand5 = new JCheckBox("Chrystler");

    JCheckBox color1 = new JCheckBox("Black");
    JCheckBox color2 = new JCheckBox("Silver");
    JCheckBox color3 = new JCheckBox("Red");
    JCheckBox color4 = new JCheckBox("Blue");

    JCheckBox drive1 = new JCheckBox("AWD");
    JCheckBox drive2 = new JCheckBox("TWD");

    JButton beginBtn = new JButton("Begin");
    JButton exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");

    //Constructor
    public Rental()
    {
        super("MyDrive");
        cont.add(testPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        testPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        cont.setLayout(border); //border layout for the container

        //Opening Screen
        beginBtn.addActionListener(this);
        beginBtn.setToolTipText("Being your rental process");
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
        welcomePnl.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        welcomePnl.add(titleLbl);
        welcomePnl.add(info);
        info.setVisible(true);
        cont.add(info, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cont.add(welcomePnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        titleLbl.setFont(myFont);

        cont.add(btnPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btnPnl.setLayout(flow);
        btnPnl.setBackground(Color.black);
        btnPnl.add(beginBtn);
        beginBtn.setVisible(false);
        btnPnl.add(carBtn);
        carBtn.setVisible(false);
        btnPnl.add(exitBtn);

        nameField.setVisible(false);
        lastName.setVisible(false);
        carBtn.addActionListener(this);
        carBtn.setVisible(false);
        rentalPnl.add(carBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        rentalPnl.add(nameField);
        rentalPnl.add(lastName);
        rentalPnl.setLayout(flow);
        cont.add(rentalPnl);

        // for logo//
                Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myDrive.png"));
                custom= new JButton(b);
                welcomePnl.add(custom);

                welcomePnl.add(yesBox);
                welcomePnl.add(noBox);

                yesBox.addActionListener(this);
                noBox.addActionListener(this);

        //carPnl.add(carLbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        brandPnl.setLayout(grid1);
        brandPnl.setVisible(false);
        brandPnl.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        brandPnl.add(brand1);
        brandPnl.add(brand2);
        brandPnl.add(brand3);
        brandPnl.add(brand4);
        brandPnl.add(brand5);

        colorPnl.setLayout(grid1);
        colorPnl.setVisible(false);
        colorPnl.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        colorPnl.add(color1);
        colorPnl.add(color2);
        colorPnl.add(color3);
        colorPnl.add(color4);

        carPnl.add(drive1);
        carPnl.add(drive2);
        carPnl.setVisible(false);
        cont.add(brandPnl, border.EAST);
        cont.add(colorPnl, border.WEST);
        cont.add(carPnl);
        carLbl.setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source == yesBox)
        {
            beginBtn.setVisible(true);
        }

        if(source == noBox)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if(source == beginBtn)
        {
            welcomePnl.setVisible(false);
            btnPnl.setVisible(true);
            btnPnl.remove(beginBtn);
            btnPnl.add(carBtn);
            carBtn.setVisible(true);

            rentalPnl.setVisible(true);
            nameField.setVisible(true);
            String fName = nameField.getText();
            lastName.setVisible(true);
            String lName = lastName.getText();
        }

        if(nameField != null & lastName != null && source == carBtn)
        {
            carBtn.setEnabled(true);
            rentalPnl.setVisible(false);
            carLbl.setVisible(true);
            brandPnl.setVisible(true);
            colorPnl.setVisible(true);
            cont.add(carLbl, border.NORTH);
        }

        if(source == exitBtn)
            System.exit(0);
    }

    //Main Method
    //Sets the size of the myDrive screen- size is not resizable (cannot be changed while using program)
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rental r1 = new Rental(); //new rental
        r1.setSize(600,600);
        r1.setVisible(true);
        r1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        r1.setResizable(false);

        try {
            // to get a connection to the SQL database//
            String dbUrl = "jcbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo";
            String user = "student";
            String password= "student";

            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
            //a statement object, to execute the SQL query
            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            //insert a new employee//
            System.out.println("Inserting a new employee to database\n");

            //using the statement object to insert data, the executeUpdate statemnt is a method to handle any update to the database, can be used for insert, update, and deletes//
            //demo code below//
            /*int rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate(

                    //"insert into employees " + "(last_name, first_name, email, department, salary)" + "values" + "('Wright, 'Eric', 'eric.wright@foo.com', 'HR', 33000.00)"
                    //);

                    "insert into employees " + "(last_name, first_name, email, department, salary)" + "values" + "(" + name2 + "," + name1 + "," + onlinemail + ")"
                    );
            */
            //this will return a result set//
            ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from employees order by last_name");

            // Process the result set, reads data from each row

            // getter method to print out the last and first name from the result set//
            while (myRs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("last_name") + ", " + myRs.getString(("first_name")));
            } 

            }

            catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*
            finally {

                if (myRs != null)
                {
                    myRs.close();
                }
            }
            */
        }

    public String getBrand() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColor() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getYear() 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMiles() 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDriveType() 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is setting four separate panels to the `CENTER` of the panel with a `BorderLayout`. Two explicitly and the other two by default (from not specifying a parameter when added). Which of the four components do you expect to appear in a space that can display exactly one? BTW - For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: If you look, the panels are being used at different times. Certain panels don't become visible until buttons are pressed on the screen.

Comment: *"If you look.."* If you'd post an MCVE, I'd have looked more closely, and the MCVE probably would not have had 4 panels being added to the one area of a container.

Comment: I am just looking for some help as to where I went wrong. I understand my code is adding multiple panels to the center but if there is a different way to do this I am very open to suggestions and help. I was just having trouble adding to the center since nothing was appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the layout before adding components using the layout:

```
    cont.setLayout(border); //border layout for the container
    cont.add(testPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: If you look at the fourth line of code within the constructor the layout is being set to border

Comment: @MattLeClair, the default layout manager for the content pane of the JFrame is the BorderLayout. So you don't need to do anything. The problem with your code is that you add components to the frame then reset the layout manager so now you have an empty BorderLayout with no components to manage. Simple solution is to just get rid of the setLayout(...) statement.